# PHP замена кавычек и безопасность

Tags: php, smarty

Всем привет! Есть PHP код функции:

```
function strip_mq_gpc($arg)
{
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  {
    $arg = str_replace('"',"'",$arg);
    $arg = stripslashes($arg);
    return $arg;
  } 
  else
  {
    $arg = str_replace('"',"'",$arg);
    return $arg;
  }
}
```

и его использование

```
$conn = &ADONewConnection($DBTYPE);
$conn->PConnect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD, $DBNAME);
@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
$sql = "SELECT * from config";
$rsc = $conn->Execute($sql);

if($rsc){while(!$rsc->EOF)
{
$field = $rsc->fields['setting'];
$config[$field] = $rsc->fields['value'];
STemplate::assign($field, strip_mq_gpc($config[$field]));
@$rsc->MoveNext();
}}
```

в MySQL таблице:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `config` (
  `setting` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `value` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

вопрос: как параметры в определении Smarty assign связаны с кавычками(',")
`str_replace('"',"'",$arg);`? Для чего их надо менять?

Comment: Ну я могу лишь предположить. Что ваши данные передаются в чистом виде и скорее всего чистым запросом, следовательно меняются для того чтобы не нарушался запрос. Например часть запроса: `...SET value => "te'st"...`, очевидно что если вместо `'` была-бы `"`, то запрос нарушился. Больше у меня нет адекватных предположений :<

Comment: @Manitikyl вопрос про smarty а не sql

Comment: возможно значение, которое вы передаете в шаблон, и потом подставляете, подставляется как то так: `<tag attr="{$field} some-value">` в таком случае, наличие `"` в параметре сломает html верстку. Поэтому он заменяется на одинарную кавычку. В целом это костыль какой-то, подобные обработки касаются шаблона, и должны проводится там наподобие `{$field|replace:"..."|escape}`

Comment: нашел такие примерные данные в таблице с значениями(не я писал этот код и бд): поле - metakeywords = значения - answer, script, answers, questions здесь кавычка будет означать тег meta без косяка 
вот header.tpl -  <meta name="keywords" content="{if $pagetitle ne ""}{$pagetitle},{/if}{if $metakeywords ne ""}{$metakeywords},{/if}{$site_name}" />

Comment: @teran я если честно чета даже не подумал, увидел `get_magic_quotes_gpc` а это ближе к бд. это получается что у смарту такой attr-эскейпер? ха. слава богу не юзаю его...

Comment: @Manitikyl это шляпа какая-то. в смарти все нормально

Comment: @teran ну последняя фраза была больше `шуткой`, чем правдой (хотя смарту все равно не юзаю). Я верю что у смарти там должно быть нормально, ибо у него достаточное комьюнити чтобы таких косяков не допускать, а практик по поводу эскейперов свыше горы. Так что возможно действительно шляпа 90ых годов.

Answer (score 1):

Вы говорите, что поля вставляются  в шаблон следующим образом:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{if $pagetitle ne ""}{$pagetitle},{/if}{if $metakeywords ne ""}{$metakeywords},{/if}{$site_name}" />
```

давайте упростим это немного, т.к. конструкция `ne ""` смысла не имеет.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{if $pagetitle}{$pagetitle},{/if}{if $metakeywords}{$metakeywords},{/if}{$site_name}" />
```

Если опустить тот факт, что в целом `meta keywords` в современном мире вещь практически игнорируемая поисковиками, вернемся к факту, что слова могут быть как разделены запятыми,  так и пробелами. Так что, можно вовсе убрать все эти `{if}`

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{$pagetitle} {$metakeywords} {$site_name}" />
```

Дак вот, давайте представим, что поле `$site_name` содержит значение `ООО "Рога и Копыта"`, а остальные для примера пустые. Что мы получим при простой подстановке:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="  ООО "Рога и Копыта"" />
```

Что делает нашу разметку некорректной, а часть `Рога и Копыта""` стала мусором.

Для этого ваш код с помощью нехитрого костыля заменяет двойные кавычки на одинарные, и удаляет слэши. В целом задача экранирования подобных вещей это задача представления. Так что у вас тут три очевидных пути:

- Заменить эти двойные кавычки, как вы и делали
- Удалить их вовсе
- Заменить на html-сущности

Только вот решать это надо прямо там в шаблоне (на примере одной переменной):

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{$site_name|replace:'"':''}" />
<meta name="keywords" content="{$site_name|escape}" />
```

Смысла использовать кавычки в ключевых словах нет, так что этот вариант не привожу.

Модификаторы можно группировать, переменные тоже в целом можно объединить в строку, так что при подозрении, что контент надо экранировать и удалять кавычки, все это вы можете свести к такой конструкции:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{"$pagetitle $keywords $site_name"|replace:'"':""|escape}" />
```

или просто экранируются по отдельности

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{$pagetitle|escape} {$keywords|escape} {$site_name|escape}" />
```

всяческие вызовы `strip_mq_gpc` из кода удаляются за ненужностью.